# Problems with postgresql insert

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, spring-mybatis

I would like to know the solution to this.

1 ~ 5000 inserts are possible without trouble
However, I want to know the solution when the error comes out.
Thank you first

> ```
> Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
> ; SQL []; An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.] with root cause
> java.io.IOException: Tried to send an out-of-range integer as a 2-byte value: 67746
> ```

```
<insert id="insertLog" parameterType="java.util.HashMap">
<if test='logList.size != 0'>
    insert into log(
        result,
        path,
        date
    )values
    <foreach collection='logList' item='item' separator=','>
    (
        #{item.result},
        #{item.path},
        #{item.date}
    )
    </foreach>
</if>
```

and log table here..!

```
create table log (no serial primary key, date varchar(50), path varchar(500),result varchar(10));
```

Comment: can you paste the table structure and the row causing the error.  It says `out-of-range integer as a 2-byte value: 67746`, are you sure you are not trying to insert a bigger value in a smaller column.

Comment: Thank you for answer I will add mybatis insert code

Comment: 10,000 lists are passed as parameters in map form ... plz I would like to hear your advice.

Comment: Which version of PostgreSQL and which version of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver?

Comment: postgresql-42.1.1.jre6 // postgresql 9.4.1212.jar thanks for the help
!

Comment: Both are versions of a PostgreSQL JDBC driver, again: which driver version are you **really** using, and what is your PostgreSQL **server** version? If you have both versions of the driver on your classpath, that might also cause problems.